# Designing concurrent HTTP URL connections

Tags: java, webservice-client

We are designing a client server system.
N numbers of clients can connect to the server to send multiple messages. The server inserts the message in the database and post the messages to an external server and returns a unique id to the client for the client to track the message.

To avoid bottlenecks and IO wait time would like split this service into two task

1. Record details in the Database
2. Batch process which will send 20 http post using

   ```
   Task sendMessage =new Task[20]
   ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 20 );
   //get the list of message not send from database send them and update the database
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
       threadExecutor.execute( task[i] );//send message via HTTP post
   }
   ```

Is this a good design. Is It good to run point 2 separately to improve performance.
Also In above case each thread will connect to the database and update it would that cause locks or dirty writes?

Comment: Can the external server poll the database instead of relying on your server to send messages? That way they would be disconnected.

Comment: do not try to prematurely optimize your design.  Write the code the simplest correct way, then profile and fix bottlenecks based on real numbers rather than conjecture.

Comment: We are sending message to the external server which inturn handles and process the message.So after sending the message the external server acknowledges the message is sent.

Comment: Also Dmitry , we have tried the first synchronous method where client sends the message to server.Server adds to database and sends to the external server.If there is bottleneck with the database the HTTP post also have issues.Thats the reason we are trying second approach

Comment: @AKV:Please improve your accept range.It discourages people from helping you